# Problem passing a variable in pug template engine language

Tags: html, css, pug

I am passing a url to the pug template

```
img.img_pattern(src= '#{url}'+'/pattern.svg' alt='pattern')
```

But this is not working. Anyone have an idea how to pass a variable to an src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backticks, template literals. Example below.

```js
- var url = "duckduckgo"
 img(src=`https://external-content.${url}.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftechtrends.intelegain.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F01%2FDuckDuckGo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1`)
```

https://codepen.io/antlis/pen/BaRQQGr